# Omniauth in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I am currently working with an application where I am trying to add in authentication.  I installed my two gems `bcrypt-ruby` and `omniauth-identity`.  I then added a new file in my config/initializers folder that contains these contents....

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity, on_failed_registration: lambda { |env|
    IdentitiesController.action(:new).call(env)
  }

  OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new { |env|
    OmniAuth::FailureEndpoint.new(env).redirect_to_failure
  }
end
```

---

When I try to create my identity model in the terminal I keep getting this syntax error

```
rails generate model identity name:string email:string password_digest:string

syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
  provider :identity, on_failed_registration: lambda { |env|
                                         ^
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of Ruby you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using Ruby 1.9 syntax, but my hunch is that you tried to generate the model using a Ruby 1.8 VM.  Can you run `ruby --version` and confirm?

Comment: Yes I'm running ruby 1.8.7 for some reason. Would I then just run rvm install 1.9.2?

Comment: ...and `rvm use 1.9.2` after that.

Comment: you can also set it up as a default by using `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity, on_failed_registration: lambda { |env|
    IdentitiesController.action(:new).call(env)
  }
```

try

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity, :on_failed_registration => lambda { |env|
    IdentitiesController.action(:new).call(env)
  }
```

You seem to be running Ruby 1.8.

Comment: Yes, ...and run `rvm use 1.9.2` after that.